# Checking boxes for items passed through context in Django

Tags: jquery, django, checkbox, django-templates, django-mptt

I am using `django-mptt` with the following code to display a tree structure of categories, sub-categories (and so on) with checkboxes. The idea being that the user can choose which categories to use.

```
{% load mptt_tags %}    
<ul >
{% recursetree nodes %}
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="{{ node.id }}" value="{{ node.id }}"name="category"/>
        {{ node }}
        {% if not node.is_leaf_node %}
            <ul>
                {{ children }}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}
    </li>
{% endrecursetree %}
</ul>
```

I have the checking of the boxes working as I want ([similarly to this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18233624/uncheck-parent-checkbox-if-one-child-is-unchecked/18237618#18237618)), but I'm having trouble figuring out how to check the previously checked boxes from the start when the user opens the page to edit the selection.

How can I have the checkboxes checked for the `node.id`s I'm passing through in the `context = {'selected_ids': selected_ids}` when the page loads?

Comment: use python to add the selected attribute if the child/parent is selected on the serverside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not do it in the template language?

```
<input type="checkbox" {% if node.id in selected_ids %} checked="checked"{% endif %} id="{{ node.id }}" value="{{ node.id }}" name="category"/>
```